# Linear Algebra - If A is invertible then A+I is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

Prove the given statement true, or give a counterexample to show that it is false.

If $A$ is an $n*n$ invertible matrix, then $A+I_{n}$ is invertible.

I did some examples and found the statement to be true. But how do i prove it for general case.

Comment: Did you try $A = -I_n$?

Comment: I am not aware of this equality

Comment: You missed his point. Is the zero matrix invertible?

Comment: I think we can almost say that the opposite is true. if $A$ is invertible there exist a $\lambda$ such that $(A+\lambda I)$ is not invertable.

Comment: Another super important point, how can doing a few examples show a statement about infinitely many things to be true?

Comment: @david thanks for the tip. zero matrix is not invertible therefore statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

"*If $A$ is an $n*n$ invertible matrix, then $A+I_{n}$ is invertible*"

is false.

Indeed it is easy to find a couterexample. Let assume $A=-I$ then, since $A^{-1}=A$, $A$ is invertible but $A+I=[0]$.

Comment: @amWhy what is your problem now? Please avoid useless comments and be polite. I've seen Robert's comments but it is not a full answer, indeed Hassan didn't understan his hint.

Comment: I thought you might want to know that she did the same thing to me some days ago.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Well, together we can bear him better!